Why differences in pyspark api between HDI and OSS
Tonight I spent a lot of time trying to investigate a difference between the HDI version 3.3.1 and the Apache OSS version 3.3.1.  I am looking in particular at worker.py.  That file can be found in HDI (5.1.5.6) where their Spark version is referred to as 3.3.1.5.1.5.6.
Notice below that cpus are deserialized into the task context as a double.
... continued...

But if we look at worker.py in the OSS github project (https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/branch-3.3) then we find it is deserialized as an integer.
taskContext._cpus = read_int(infile)

What is the reason that the Spark core would work so differently in OSS and HDI?  Is there any place I can find the HDI version of the code?  The product prides itself on adhering to open source spark.  So it is a bit disappointing to be finding these differences.  It seems to me that any external api with python should behave the same as it does in OSS, assuming the same version of Spark.
I'm not as interested in the specific detail as I am about the principles that would cause HDI to be different than OSS.
